# How to assign arbitrary LaTeX text to a variable for use in different places in a document?

Tags: macros, programming

I have lots of LaTeX text duplication in my files, since the file has to compile with pdflatex and `tex4ht` and `text4ht` does not support all packages, So my files are littered with things like this all over the place

```
\ifdefined\HCode
  \begin{A}        
       same stuff
  \end{A}
\else
  \begin{B}
      same stuff
  \end{B}
\fi
```

Where the difference between the two cases in just the environment, where the stuff inside is the same. So I have to copy paste `same stuff` in two places and remember if I change it in one place, to change it in the other place.

I can't write the above as

```
\ifdefined\HCode
  \begin{A}        
\else
  \begin{B}
 \fi
       same stuff
\ifdefined\HCode
  \end{A}        
\else
  \end{B}
\fi
```

Since this will not compile in general.  What I'd like to do, which seems to be impossible, is to define what is called a `variable` in normal programming languages and assign to the `variable` whatever latex text I want, telling Latex not to process it or look at it, but just hold to it as literal, and then replace the variable inside the environment, like this

```
\def\myVariable{  whatever I want goes here } %tell Latex not to look at it
```

Now I can write

```
\ifdefined\HCode
  \begin{A}        
       \myVariable
  \end{A}
\else
  \begin{B}
      \myVariable
  \end{B}
\fi
```

Now the code is not duplicated. But I do not know how to do the above.

This has to be done inside the document, not in preamble. So I can allocate the variable next to where it is used.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}% 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}    
\ifdefined\HCode
\begin{equation}
  3\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}}+2\frac{dy}{dt}+y\left(  t\right) = u(t)
\end{equation}
\else
\begin{dmath*}
  3\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}}+2\frac{dy}{dt}+y\left(  t\right) = u(t)
\end{dmath*}
\fi 
\end{document}
```

**I tried:** `\let` and `\def`, these did not work. I tried `\newcommand`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}% 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\variable}{3\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}}+2\frac{dy}{dt}+y\left(  t\right) = u(t)}
\ifdefined\HCode
\begin{equation}
  \variable
\end{equation}
\else
\begin{dmath*}
  \variable
\end{dmath*}
\fi 
\end{document}
```

But it gave an error `Undefined control sequence. \variable`

**ps.** The above error was due to a typo. Please ignore. Typo corrected.

**question is**: How to change the above, so not to duplicate the code used in both places?

Comment: The unknown command sequence is rather `\3` instead of `\variable`.

Comment: I think you need another input format and three processors to get the three different ouotputs.Maybe pandoc can do all of them at once.

Comment: Note that the tex error message would _not_ have been `Undefined control sequence. \variable` it would have shown that `\3` was undefined and `\variable` was the location of the error. If your editor is only showing you a mangled form of the error message then complain to its developers.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the error message was `Undefined control sequence. \variable`, that is why I did not notice that I had `\3` there. Here is screen shot fyi, ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fOM6j.png) may be then this is an issue with texstudio

Comment: @Nasser No. As I say that is _not_ the tex error message, that is your editor showing you the start of a message, and the end of the message, and omitting the important part that says which command is undefined. Look at tex's console output or log file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly as you suggested, but `\newif` is a simple solution. Your `A` and `B` environments replaced by exemplary theorem-like ones.

Edit: enlarged, according to suggestion from comment. The old picture left.

```
   \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\def\myVariable{  whatever I want goes here } %tell Latex not to look at it

Now I can write

\newif\ifHcode

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

%\ifdefined\HCode
\def\usemyVariable{
\ifHcode
  \begin{thm}        
       \myVariable
  \end{thm}
\else
  \begin{lem}
      \myVariable
  \end{lem}
\fi
}

\usemyVariable

\Hcodetrue

\usemyVariable

\def\myVariable{3\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}}+2\frac{dy}{dt}+y\left( t\right) = u(t)}

\def\usemyVariable{
\ifHcode
\begin{equation}
  \myVariable
\end{equation}
\else
\begin{displaymath}
  \myVariable
\end{displaymath}
\fi 
}

\usemyVariable

\Hcodefalse

\usemyVariable



\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Keep the tests out of your document body:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}% 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ifdefined\HCode
\newenvironment{myequation}
{\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}
\else
\usepackage{breqn}
\newenvironment{myequation}
{\begin{dmath*}}{\end{dmath*}\ignorespacesafterend}
\fi

\begin{document}    


\begin{myequation}
  3\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}}+2\frac{dy}{dt}+y\left(  t\right) = u(t)
\end{myequation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Annotation 1 -- about "variables" that get initialized somewhere within the document-environment's body but are used from the beginning of the document-environment's body:

Use the LaTeX2e-kernel's infrastructure for defining the \label..\ref-
mechanism and define your own -- references will be resolved after the
*second* LaTeX-run:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
% !! In case you wish to use the hyperref-package, have the things
% !! between \makeatletter..\makeatother done _before_ loading the
% !! hyperref package.
\let\MySaved@setref=\@setref
\let\MySaved@newl@bel=\@newl@bel
\AtEndDocument{\let\MySaved@newl@bel=\@testdef}%
\newcommand\@currentphraselabel{}%
\newcommand\phraselabel[2]{%
  \@bsphack
  \protected@edef\@currentphraselabel{#2}%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newphraselabel{#1}{\@currentphraselabel}}%
  \@esphack
}%
\newcommand*\newphraselabel{\MySaved@newl@bel{MyVar}}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\phraseref[1]{%
  \expandafter\MySaved@setref\csname MyVar@#1\endcsname\@firstofone{#1}%
}%
\makeatother

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is the value of myVariable: \phraseref{myVariable}.

This is when myVariable gets initialized.
\phraselabel{myVariable}{MyVariable's value}%

This is again the value of myVariable: \phraseref{myVariable}.

\end{document}
```

## Annotation 2 -- about forking when using environments:

Define the environment to fork depending on HCode being defined:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\AtIfDefindeHCode{%
  \ifdefined\HCode\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
}%
\newcommand\envA{This is start of env in case HCode defined.}
\@ifundefined{endenvA}%
             {\def\endenvA{This is end of env in case HCode defined.}}%
             {\newcommand\endenvA{}}% <- trigger the error-message
\newcommand\envB{This is start of env in case HCode undefined.}
\@ifundefined{endenvB}%
              {\def\endenvB{This is end of env in case HCode undefined.}}%
              {\newcommand\endenvB{}}% <- trigger the error-message
\newenvironment{AorB}%
              {\AtIfDefindeHCode{\envA}{\envB}}%
              {\AtIfDefindeHCode{\endenvA}{\endenvB}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\HCode{defined}%
\begin{AorB}
Some text in AorB.
\end{AorB}

\let\HCode=\BIZarrEaNDThereFOreHOpeFullyUnDEFiNED
\begin{AorB}
Some text in AorB.
\end{AorB}

\end{document}
```

Ulrich Diez